# webpack-dev-server can not reload when an obj changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userName: 'naraku',
            itemTotal: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            nickName: 'ljs'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        notify: function(e){
            var i = 0;
        }
    },
    components: {
        'hello': require('../components/hello.vue')
    }
}
```

the code will export a Vue Instance, if I modify it as below:

```
console.log('change'); // 
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userName: 'naraku',
            itemTotal: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            nickName: 'ljs'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        notify: function(e){
            var i = 0;
        }
    },
    components: {
        'hello': require('../components/hello.vue')
    }
}
```

Tt worked. But I modify like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userName: 'hello',  // change the userName
            itemTotal: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            nickName: 'ljs'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        notify: function(e){
            var i = 0;
        }
    },
    components: {
        'hello': require('../components/hello.vue')
    }
}
```

It dos not work. There are no changes on the view. Why?

Comment: You mean hot reloading?

Comment: yes! yours is the correct statement

Comment: Maybe you have `data()` already have called at the hot reloading moment?